# vbs script that cycles .ico files

Tags: vbscript, slideshow, ico

What iam trying to figure out is how to have a vbs script cycle through different .ico files while still on the desktop. almost like a slide show of the different .ico files. is it possible?

here is what i have so far but it does not cycle the .ico files

```
     set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
     set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\Movies Folder.lnk")
     oShellLink.TargetPath = "J:\Movies"
     oShellLink.IconLocation = "C:\MoviesShortcut\Movies.Ico"
     wscript.sleep 500
     oShellLink.IconLocation = "C:\MoviesShortcut\tv1.Ico"
     oShellLink.Description = "movies"
     oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop
```

Comment: Where do you want them to be *displayed* when you cycle through them? When you say slideshow, do you mean you want them to be full screen?

Comment: no just trying to have the icon for the shortcut cycle through different .ico, so for example i have movies.ico, now i want the icon to change within 5 seconds to tv1.ico and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1):

If the sample code works and does indeed perform one change of the icon after 5 seconds then I think you will need to add an "Open Do Loop" combined with a "For" to run through all files in the folder, something like:

```
oShellLink.TargetPath = "J:\Movies"

Do
    For Each File in OShellLink.TargetPath
        oShellLink.IconLocation = File.Path
        wscript.sleep 500
    Next
Loop
```

My vbs is a little rusty but hopefully that will point you in the right direction.